# jQuery MaskMoney - set input to to beginning of field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qct6U/) to demonstrate my problem. When I focus on the field the cursor goes to the end. You start typing cents before you dollars. I do not want this behavior. I want it to type dollars until the user presses '.'

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not let them type what they want, then mask it when they leave the cell?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently supported by the plugin. We have this issue open https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/issues/33 that asks for that feature, but nobody in working on it right now. Pull requests are welcome :)